# How to prevent downstream errors from blocking query execution?

Tags: database, union, missing-data

I have a query that pulls from two separate databases using a union all.

Unfortunately, due to some unresolved IT issues, sometimes DB #2 (the one after the union all statement) does not get restored each night.

This means, when my automated reporting kicks off early in the morning, I often experience total failure because the second DB is missing.

Is there some command that will allow me to run part one (pre-union) if DB #2 doesn't exist?

Thank you!

--EDIT-- I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Please include what database you are using (eg: MySQL, SQLite, SQL Server, etc.) as well as what language or technology you are using to access that database. There may be solutions to mitigate this type of error, but nothing that would be applicable to all databases.

Comment: Sorry! I'm using SQL Server.